# how do I "Order by min(subquery)"?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a list of dates.  Each row has multiple dates concatenated as a single string.  I want to order the rows by the minimum date in each row.

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT br.bm_tracking_number,
         (SELECT TOLIST(APPT.fact_date) 
            FROM bm_fact APPT 
           WHERE APPT.bm_review_sk = br.bm_review_sk
             AND APPT.fact_type_code=183050) "Appointments"
    FROM BM_REVIEW br
   WHERE row_delete_date_time IS NULL
ORDER BY MIN(SELECT APPT.fact_date 
               FROM bm_fact APPT
              WHERE APPT.bm_review_sk = br.bm_review_sk
               AND APPT.fact_type_code = 183050);
```

I am getting an Oracle error (00936 missing expression) on the order by line.  Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
  SELECT br.bm_tracking_number,
         TOLIST(bf.fact_date)
    FROM BM_REVIEW br
    JOIN BM_FACT bf ON bf.bm_review_sk = br.bm_review_sk
                   AND bf.fact_type_code = 183050
   WHERE br.row_delete_date_time IS NULL
GROUP BY br.bm_tracking_number
ORDER BY MIN(bf.fact_date)
```

...will give you a list, ordered by the `fact_date` in ascending order.

Comment: Shouldn't that have [GROUP BY br.bm_tracking_number] in there?  And then [ORDER BY MIN(bf.fact_date)]?

Comment: @Dems: Correct, added missing GROUP BY.

Comment: You still need the MIN() aggregate in the ORDER BY as you're not grouping by that field.

Comment: I don't have Oracle to test with, so I'll have to take your word for that.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know

Comment: I don't either, but you'd need it in any version of SQL I know of.  You simply can't "GROUP BY x ORDER BY y"

Answer (score 0):

Only glancing at it, but one thing is that you didn't alias bm_fact to APPT in the subquery.

**EDIT:**

Okay, you fixed that.

How about putting the MIN() inside the sub query?

```
ORDER BY (SELECT MIN(APPT.fact_date) ...)
```

Comment: D'oh!  I fixed that.  It is aliased correctly in SQL Developer.  I can't copy and paste as that is on a secure network.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: putting the MIN inside the subquery also worked.  Rexem's query seemed to run faster, though, so I marked that as the accepted answer.  Thanks, Dems!